# Grails, Service Transaction not working correctly

Tags: grails, transactions

Grails version 2.4.3

My code below, when I throw a Run Time Exception in the method I am working in handled correctly and I can continue on and save. However if I throw a Run Time Exception in my SecondLevelService, I get an error 
secondLevelService.TestA() all it does is 
`throw new RuntimeException('This is a Run time exception Second Level')`

> Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

as the error says it is rolled back and nothing is saved.

Can anyone help me understand why the difference, I wish it was handled closer to the thrown exception within the method.  By turning off transactions in the second level service the error is handled, but that will not work for my requirements.

```
class FirstLevelService {
    SecondLevelService secondLevelService
    def TestA() {
        com.Author author = null
        com.Book book =  null


        try {


            //Create a database record
            author = new com.Author(firstName:'TestXXX', lastName: 'User XXX' )
            book = new com.Book(title: 'Test Book XXX', pageCount: 1 )

            author.addToBooks(book)

            println 'Book Save'
            author.save(failOnError:true)
            println 'Is Dirty 1st Save:' + author.isDirty()
            println author.books?.size()

            //Fail with Runtime exception this is do other things to the book and author
            throw new RuntimeException('This is a Run time exception')
            //secondLevelService.TestA()
        }
        catch (RuntimeException re) { //Cause I am catching any saving should be okay
            println 'Exception caught'
            println re.message
        } finally {

            //But make the change to author anyway
            println 'Change the first Name'
            author.firstName = 'TestYYY ' + new Date().toString()
            println 'Is Dirty before Save:' + author.isDirty()


            println 'Save Change the first Name: ' + author.firstName

            if (!author.validate()) {
                author.errors.each {
                    println it
                }
            }

            println 'Is Dirty before 2nd Save:' + author.isDirty()
            author.save(failOnError:true)
            println 'Is Dirty:' + author.isDirty()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever a RTE or an Error is thrown **outside** of a service bean (most likely back to the controller), transaction is rolled back. Transaction is not marked as rollback only in the former case because it was handled and not thrown out from the service bean.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it was attempting to be caught, in the calling bean, so to expand, that second service can be called from a controller or another service and so we are logging errors differently based on service vs controller.  So how would handle this in the service to log the error, when the DB is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is exactly the expected behavior. A RuntimeException, that is thrown in a Service and is not caught in the same service, leads to a Rollback of the transaction (see [grails service docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/services.html): 12.1 Declarative Transactions).

If you want to get around it, you have different possibilities. The first one is, that this Rollback behavior is only true for RuntimeExceptions or Errors - not for checked Exceptions. This is true although groovy has a little different understanding of checked exceptions vs. unchecked exceptions. The point that the docs make here is, that Spring is aware of it and that is the reason.

Another possible solution i can think of is not not share the transaction within the two services. This should work since the default Transaction Propagation behavior is [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html#PROPAGATION_REQUIRED). This means, that if the second service creates a runtime exception `transaction.setRollbackOnly()` is called on the whole transaction. So you can either require a new transaction within the second service or don't use a transaction at all.